# uislider: open preview pictures like magazine apps

Tags: iphone, ipad, uislider

I'm using a `UISlider` for an magazine app. I changed the thumb, max and min, but is there a way  to open a preview picture with the slider like a lot of magazine app.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do it yourself, it's not included in `UISlider`.

You'll have to track each changes in value of your `UISlider`, and at each changes, show a new picture at the top of you `UISlider` (or where ever you want).

Comment: Than do you know a tutorial to put differents pictures in a popover up to the uislider ?

Comment: I don't know if your app target the iPad but this would be perfect with a few modifications. http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/29/adding-a-uipopover-to-uislider/